# R: Expand year range for some countries in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following problem: I have a dataset of all NATO states that includes yearly membership from 1980-2020. Now I want to include all years since NATO's founding (1949-2020). So for example for Belgium, Canada, Denmark, France, Iceland, Italy, Luxembourg,  Netherlands, Norway, Portugal,  United Kingdom, United States there should be rows added for the years 1949-1980.

Here is a simplified version of the dataset:

```
country <- rep(c("Belgium", "Albania"), each= 10)
countrycode <- rep(c(56, 8), each=10)
year <- rep(c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000), 2)
   
df <- data.frame(country, countrycode, year)

   country countrycode year
1  Belgium          56 1990
2  Belgium          56 1991
3  Belgium          56 1992
4  Belgium          56 1994
5  Belgium          56 1995
6  Belgium          56 1996
7  Belgium          56 1997
8  Belgium          56 1998
9  Belgium          56 1999
10 Belgium          56 2000
11 Albania           8 1990
12 Albania           8 1991
13 Albania           8 1992
14 Albania           8 1994
15 Albania           8 1995
16 Albania           8 1996
17 Albania           8 1997
18 Albania           8 1998
19 Albania           8 1999
20 Albania           8 2000
```

In this example, how would I most efficiently expand the years for Belgium to 1949, while leaving Albania as it is?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we could create a dataframe with Belgium 1949 - 1989 and then use `bind_rows`:

```
country <- "Belgium"
countrycode <- 56
year <- 1949:1989
df1 <- data.frame(country, countrycode, year)

library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df, df1) %>% 
  arrange(country, year)
```

Output

```
country countrycode year
1  Albania           8 1990
2  Albania           8 1991
3  Albania           8 1992
4  Albania           8 1994
5  Albania           8 1995
6  Albania           8 1996
7  Albania           8 1997
8  Albania           8 1998
9  Albania           8 1999
10 Albania           8 2000
11 Belgium          56 1949
12 Belgium          56 1950
13 Belgium          56 1951
14 Belgium          56 1952
15 Belgium          56 1953
16 Belgium          56 1954
17 Belgium          56 1955
18 Belgium          56 1956
19 Belgium          56 1957
20 Belgium          56 1958
21 Belgium          56 1959
22 Belgium          56 1960
23 Belgium          56 1961
24 Belgium          56 1962
25 Belgium          56 1963
26 Belgium          56 1964
27 Belgium          56 1965
28 Belgium          56 1966
29 Belgium          56 1967
30 Belgium          56 1968
31 Belgium          56 1969
32 Belgium          56 1970
33 Belgium          56 1971
34 Belgium          56 1972
35 Belgium          56 1973
36 Belgium          56 1974
37 Belgium          56 1975
38 Belgium          56 1976
39 Belgium          56 1977
40 Belgium          56 1978
41 Belgium          56 1979
42 Belgium          56 1980
43 Belgium          56 1981
44 Belgium          56 1982
45 Belgium          56 1983
46 Belgium          56 1984
47 Belgium          56 1985
48 Belgium          56 1986
49 Belgium          56 1987
50 Belgium          56 1988
51 Belgium          56 1989
52 Belgium          56 1990
53 Belgium          56 1991
54 Belgium          56 1992
55 Belgium          56 1994
56 Belgium          56 1995
57 Belgium          56 1996
58 Belgium          56 1997
59 Belgium          56 1998
60 Belgium          56 1999
61 Belgium          56 2000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use expand.grid to create all valid combos of year and country (I think the data are small enough here). Then do a left join of all combinations with the existing data. This results in a row for every combo of country and year.

```
country <- rep(c("Belgium", "Albania"), each= 10)

allCombos <- expand.grid(unique(country), 1949:2020) %>%
    setNames(., c('country', 'year'))

countrycode <- rep(c(56, 8), each=10)
year <- rep(c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000), 2)
   
df <- data.frame(country, countrycode, year)

merge(allCombos, df, by = c('country', 'year'), all.x=TRUE)
```

Partial output:

```
    country year countrycode
1   Belgium 1949          NA
2   Belgium 1950          NA
3   Belgium 1951          NA
4   Belgium 1952          NA
5   Belgium 1953          NA
6   Belgium 1954          NA
7   Belgium 1955          NA
8   Belgium 1956          NA
9   Belgium 1957          NA
10  Belgium 1958          NA
11  Belgium 1959          NA
12  Belgium 1960          NA
```